# Gradient masking flash

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to put gradient masking effect in my 20 images.

```
var arr:Array = ["m1.jpg","m2.jpg","m3.jpg","m4.jpg","m5.jpg"];

for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    duplicateMovieClip(ho, "newImg_mc"+i , this.getNextHighestDepth()); 
    if(i < 5){
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._x = 0;
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._y = 110*i;
        this["newImg_mc"+i].loadMovie(arr[i]);
    }

    if(i >= 5 and i < 10){
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._x = 110;
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._y = 110*(i-5);
        this["newImg_mc"+i].loadMovie(arr[i-5]);
    }

    if(i >= 10 and i < 15){
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._x = 220;
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._y = 110*(i-10);
        this["newImg_mc"+i].loadMovie(arr[i-10]);
    }
    if(i >= 15 and i < 20){
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._x = 330;
        this["newImg_mc"+i]._y = 110*(i-15);
        this["newImg_mc"+i].loadMovie(arr[i-15]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `blendMode` of the mask and the masked object to [`BlendMode.LAYER`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html?allClasses=1#LAYER).